# How does git know which ssh key to use for its operations?

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I have SSH keys in place, inside `~/.ssh`. Many of them actually. So I wonder how does `git` know which one to take when it tries to connect to a repository over `git@domain.com:group/repo.git` endpoint?

Comment: > How does ssh know? It looks at your ~/.ssh/config 

It doesn't appear to use ~ (or $HOME) for this.  If you change your HOME to /tmp/mystuff it will not look in /tmp/mystuff/.ssh (The reason I am doing something like this is that often our nfs-mounted $HOME directory is not available, so I've pointed my $HOME (and ~) to a local file system.  From using strace, it appears that it looks in /etc/passwd before looking for .ssh/config (I imagine it also looks in whatever nis  or ldap registry if that's where the user's home comes from).

Comment: location of id_rsa file can be changed in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Git does not know, or care.  It just runs ssh.

How does ssh know?  It looks at your `~/.ssh/config` file (**edit**: or gets it from ssh-agent; see below):

```
Host github.com
    # IdentitiesOnly yes # see below to decide if you want this
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_id_file

Host domain.com
    IdentitiesOnly yes # again, see below
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/another_id_file
```

**Edit**: here is a link to [a Linux version of the ssh_config documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).  While each system (MacOS, Linux, the various BSDs, even the Windows ports) has its own flavor of ssh config handling, they all share most of these configurables.  Note these two items in particular (I have adjusted formatting slightly for StackOverflow markdown):

> **IdentitiesOnly**
>
> Specifies that ssh(1) should only use the authentication identity
>   files configured in the **ssh_config** files, even if ssh-agent(1) or
>   a **PKCS11Provider** offers more identities.  The argument to this
>   keyword must be “yes” or “no”.  This option is intended for situations where ssh-agent offers many different identities.  The
>   default is “no”.
>
> **IdentityFile**
>
> Specifies a file from which the user's DSA, ECDSA, ED25519 or RSA
>   authentication identity is read.  The default is `~/.ssh/identity`
>   for protocol version 1, and `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`,
>   `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` for protocol version 2.
>   Additionally, any identities represented by the authentication
>   agent will be used for authentication unless `IdentitiesOnly` is
>   set.  ssh(1) will try to load certificate information from the
>   filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to the path of a
>   specified `IdentityFile`.
>
> The file name may use the tilde syntax to refer to a user's home
>   directory or one of the following escape characters: ‘%d’ (local
>   user's home directory), ‘%u’ (local user name), ‘%l’ (local host
>   name), ‘%h’ (remote host name) or ‘%r’ (remote user name).
>
> It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in 
>   configuration files; all these identities will be tried in sequence.
>   Multiple **IdentityFile** directives will add to the list of identities
>   tried (this behaviour differs from that of other configuration
>   directives).
>
> **IdentityFile** may be used in conjunction with **IdentitiesOnly** to
>   select which identities in an agent are offered during authentication.

As [Alexey Ten noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37518346/how-does-git-know-which-ssh-key-to-use-for-its-operations/37518480?noredirect=1#comment62535957_37518480), `IdentityFile` is peculiar in that it is additive (rather than one-setting-overrides-another).

You can also run ssh (manually) with additional `-v` options to trace the connection.  In Git, you can set `GIT_SSH` to the name of a script that runs `ssh -vvv` for a temporary trace (or fuss with the log level in your `~/.ssh/config` file).  I've found this useful to debug occasionally.  (Note that you cannot pass options to ssh via `GIT_SSH`, you need a one-line script such as `ssh-vvv` with one line reading `ssh -vvv $@`.)

Comment: And in case you don't have explicit mapping, ssh just tries them all

Comment: I do not seem to have ~/.ssh/config file. If you update your answer with the case and maybe a link to a resource on how to create such file (which as I see know I need) I will accept this one.

Comment: The problem which made me ask this question was that, while I had a lot of keys in .ssh and at least three of them defined in my gitlab profile, there was only one that let me through. So I wondered why this preference.